# Apache camel - simple scan directory and ftp upload

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, message-queue

I am trying to use Apache camel to do a simple listen of a directory and upload the files via ftp onto an external location.  I am new this.

I can move my files from one directory to another with this script.  So figured I am half way there. I am now struggling to move it from one directory to the ftp server directory.  I have tested the ftp connection with an ftp client and it all works ok.

When I run it it moves the file into a directory called ".camel" but does not upload it?  Its not outputting any error?  I am not sure output or view the logs to the terminal so I can view what went wrong?  Do I need to include some kind of .process()?

**Main.class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new MoveFileRoute());
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        camelContext.stop();
    }

}
```

**MoveFileToRoute**

```
public class MoveFileRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{

        from("file://C:\\test")
          .choice()
          .when(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName} contains '*.xlsx'"))
          .to("ftp://rob@10.171.16.100/home/rob/test/?password=rob")
          .otherwise()
          .to("log://org.apache.camel.howto?showAll=true&level=DEBUG");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out..

```
.when(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName} contains '*.xlsx'"))
```

The `*` on this line breaks it..

Answer here

```
public class MoveFileRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{

        from("file://C:\\test")
          .choice()
          .when(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName} contains '.xlsx'"))
          .to("ftp://rob@10.171.16.100:21/test?password=rob")
          .otherwise()
          .to("log://org.apache.camel.howto?showAll=true&level=DEBUG");
    }


}
```

I still havent figured out how to view the logs yet though.